# Accessing explicit objects within an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Using an api call I'm fetching a range of data objects stored within an array however I only want to print out some of the objects returned.

All of the data is stored within the `$mail` variable. I'm looking to access delivered for example would it be something like `$mail->delivered`

This is the sample data returned -

```
"""
[\n
  {\n
    "count_purchased": 0,\n
    "delivered": 1,\n
    "clicked_unique": 0,\n
    "shared": 0,\n
    "mailings": 1,\n
    "year": 2016,\n
    "month": 9,\n
    "opened": 1,\n
    "opted_out": 0,\n
    "sent": 1,\n
    "signed_up": 0,\n
  },\n
  {\n
  "count_purchased": 0,\n
  "delivered": 56,\n
  "clicked_unique": 0,\n
  "shared": 0,\n
  "mailings": 31,\n
  "year": 2016,\n
  "month": 9,\n
  "opened": 1,\n
  "opted_out": 0,\n
  "sent": 102,\n
  "signed_up": 0,\n
  }\n
]
```

Comment: is it json response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enhancing the [answer of M. I.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39635328/1651011) with a little bit of explanation:

Since you are getting a `JSON` string as a response, you need to convert it. Conveniently, PHP has a function for that, most notably [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

So if your response is stored into `$mail`, then all we need to do is convert it into an `associative array` or an object of the class `\stdClass`.

Your response returns multiple objects so we need to do some work before we can access it the way, you want it to:

```
// Given the content of mail is your given json string

// The second parameter allows us to use each entry of $mailData as \stdClass.
// If you want to use an assiocative array instead, you can put in true for the second parameter.
$mailData = json_decode($mail, false); // false can also be omitted in this case.
echo $mailData[0]->sent; // 1
echo $mailData[1]->sent; // 102

// Now you are able to do fancy stuff with the data, for example loop over it.
foreach($mailData as $singleMailData) {
    // Do whatever you want with each entry. In my example I just print out the data.
    var_dump($singleMailData);
}
```

Comment: Excellent thank you for the explanation also well understood now for future use!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an `JSON` as response. Use:

```
json_decode($jsonString); // to get an `JSON` object or
json_decode($jsonString, true); // to get an associative array.
```